# Correct use of if-else function in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm doing a research project on the volume of calcification on the symptomatic or asymptomatic side of stroke.

The symptomatic side can be 1 (right) or 2 (left). For all cases, I calculated the volume of calcification on the right and left side separetly. Next, I want to compare both sides (symp. vs asymp) with respect to the total volume of calcification.

I thougt the following code was correct:

```
ds$totalcalcSymp <- if(ds$sympt_side==2) ds$totalcalcL else 
  (ds$totalcalcR)

ds$totalcalcAsymp <- if(ds$sympt_side>1) ds$totalcalcR else
  (ds$totalcalcL)
```

However, the above R code seems not to work. For the symptomatic side I get values that are similar to totalcalcR (right side). And for the asymptomatic side values of totalcalcL (left side).

I also tried work with only if statements, but still I get the same results as above. Is the problem related to the warning messages I also receive?

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What is an appropriate solution to link the correct side (totalcalcR or totalcL)  to the symptomatic and asymptomic side of stroke?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Try `ds$totalcalcSymp <- ifelse(ds$sympt_side==2, ds$totalcalcL, ds$totalcalcR)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ifelse()`:

```
ds$totalcalcSymp <- ifelse(ds$sympt_side==2, ds$totalcalcL, ds$totalcalcR)
```

Comment: Arun, aren't the two constructs logically equivalent?

Comment: First, wow! What a fast repsonse! The first code doesn't work as said by Akrun. However second code with ifelse function seems to work! I thougt the ifelse function only could be used with binary outcomes and so not for continuous variables (volume of calcification).